# How to copy text from text field to text area on drupal webform?

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

How do I copy text from text field to text area on drupal webform?

Like this:

1. Type text in text field.
2. Click insert text button.
3. Copy text from text field to text area.

Text field and text area are in the same drupal webform.

Answer (score 0):

Modify and include this JS file:

```
(function ($) {

    $(document).ready ( function () {

       $('#myInsertButton').click ( function () {  
          $('#myTextArea').val( $('#myTextfield').val() );
       }); 

    });

})(jQuery);
```

If you have not an insert button you can create one. If you create an insert button you must create it before attaching events to the button. If you don't know how to create the insert button research for "jquery append".

Hope that helps!